# Sample matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, random, statistics

I'm trying to create two matrices one that can be filled with 0's and 0.25's and another with 0's and 1's.

```
vector <- c()
for(i in 1:1000){
  dummy_qt <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0, 0.25), 44, replace = TRUE), 4, 11))
  colnames(dummy_qt) <- c(2005:2015)
  boot_qt <- dummy_qt %>%
    summarise_all(funs(sum)) %>%
    sum()/11

  dummy_y <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0, 1), 44, replace = TRUE), 4, 11))
  colnames(dummy_y) <- c(2005:2015)
  boot_y <- dummy_y %>%
    mutate(sumrow = rowSums(.)/11) %>%
    select(sumrow) %>%
    sum()

  qt_y <- sum(boot_qt, boot_y)
  vector[i] <- qt_y
}
```

After creating the matrices, I run a mathematical formula, and put it into a vector. However, I know the maximum the matrix dummy_qt can get is 1, and the dummy_y is 4, making the final result 5 if all values within the matrix are 0.25 for the first matrix and 1 for the second.

For example:

```
dummy_qt <- as.data.frame(matrix(0.25, 4, 11))
dummy_y <- as.data.frame(matrix(1, 4, 11))
boot_qt <- dummy_qt %>%
    summarise_all(funs(sum)) %>%
    sum()/11
boot_y <- dummy_y %>%
    mutate(sumrow = rowSums(.)/11) %>%
    select(sumrow) %>%
    sum()
qt_y <- sum(boot_qt, boot_y)
```

Whenever I run this, usually the histogram shows that I only get values between 0 and 3.25 which doesn't reflect the reality. Saying so, I wonder what's going wrong as they should vary between 0 and 5.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what your question is. Running the above example with `set.seed(42)`, I'm getting these quantiles `1.636364 2.295455 2.500000 2.727273 3.386364`. Why would you expect the values to reach the extremes?

Comment: @Val if you check my second code example, where all values are 0.25 for one matrix and 1 for the other, then I would expect it to be 5.

Comment: But you're specifically setting it to all `0.25` or all `1` ... the chance that happens with random sampling (as in your above example) is pretty low ... so if you have at least one value different, it can't be 0 or 5

Comment: The problem is that despite knowing that the chances of sampling to that extreme are low, I would still expect it to have it once in a while a bit higher. The issue I have is that as this reflects a real case scenario, where often we do indeed see values equal to 5, I'm not sure how to validate that. But probably this is a statistical question and not coding question. I just wonder if there's any coding option to get more extreme values.

Comment: Sounds like a statistical question ... maybe your real case scenario isn't as random. With `sample` you could set probabilities, but that won't help getting both extremes more often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it is indeed a probabilistic matter, as @Val suggested. To observe `sum(boot_qt, boot_y)` as `5` you need all the elements of `dummy_qt` to be 0.25 and all the elements of `dummy_y` to be 1. The probability of that is `2^(-88) =~ 0.32 * 10^(-26)`.

To see that, try to reduce the number of rows and columns of `dummy_qt` and `dummy_y`, you will see that you get much closer to the upper bound.

For instance, if `nr` and `nc` denote the number of rows and columns of the two matrices, respectively, then you are going to reach the upper bound in one attempt with probability `2^(-2 * nr * nc)`. Suppose that

```
nr <- nc <- 3
```

and we try 1000 times. Then the probability of observing 3.75 (the upper bound) at least once is

```
1 - (1 - 2^(-2 * nr * nc))^1000
# [1] 0.003807438
```

Still really low, but no longer essentially zero as in the initial case. Alternatively, you may want to increase the probability that an entry will be 0.25 or 1.

So now let's write down the general probability. Let `N` be the number of attemps, `p1` be the probability of drawing 0.25 and `p2` of drawing 1. Then the probability of drawing the upper bound at least once is

```
1 - (1 - (p1 * p2)^(-2 * nr * nc))^iter
```